# apt-get problem and arrow

Tags: 14.04, apt, vi

hey guys  I am new to ubuntu I am trying to use the command "apt-get install vim" but it actually not installing I cannot understand what that means so i am copying it down what the terminal is showing. I am sure vim and vi both have been installed but while using vi editor the backspace and the arrow button does not work as the way it is suppose to work.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package vim is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

Thanks

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running? You may find this useful: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=vim

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14 LTS version I am trying to update the software I hope that works.

Comment: In that case you want this: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/vim

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` and give me a ping with `@A.B.`

Answer (score 0):

`vim` is probably already installed. Use `type vim` to see, or `ls  /usr/bin/vim`

To look for  package, use `apt-cache search vim`. On my system (64 bit Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS), the `vim` executable is part of the `vim-gnome` package.

What part of the message do you not understand?

```
Package vim is not available
```

"not available". Maybe the package is not called `vim`.

The `but is referred to by another package` just means YOU referred to it.

Comment: I understand that the package is installed but the arrow and backspace keys are not working as it suppose to work.  Both the keys when hit throws some alphabet.

Comment: `vim` is emitting ESCape sequences (see `man console_codes`) to move the cursor. In your case, it is emitting the wrong ESCape sequences. Check the setting of your `TERM` environment variable, with `echo $TERM`, and try your `vim` after doing `export TERM=xterm`

Answer (score 0):

On my system it's not installed but attempting to run it provides the following suggestions:

```
The program 'vim' can be found in the following packages:
 * vim
 * vim-gnome
 * vim-tiny
 * vim-athena
 * vim-gtk
 * vim-nox
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

It's also available via the software center.

You could try the following:

[image: install vim]

You'll note you need sudo to install anything.